# Rest Sharp's AddJsonBody sending parameters in url instead of in body for a POST request

Tags: restsharp

I set my application to send a POST request with parameters to be passed in body using

qs.name = name; qs.id = id
request.AddJsonBody(qs)

But on running the application, i can see the individual parameters in my URL as query string parameters

Comment: So you want to add parameters in the body or in the URL because your title states something different than your description

Answer (score 1):

If i Understand correctly you want to send a json a in the body for a post request, You Should use `AddParameter()`, Instead of `AddJsonBody();`

Here is a quick example

```
public IRestResponse ExamplePost(int id, string name)
        {
            object tmp = new
            {
                Id = id,
                Name = name

            };
            string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(tmp);
            var Client = new RestClient();
            Client.BaseUrl = new Uri(YourEndPoint); //Your Url 
            var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
            request.Resource = string.Format("/someurl");
            request.AddParameter("application/json", json, ParameterType.RequestBody);
            IRestResponse response = Client.Execute(request);
            Logger.LogInfo($"Sending : {json}");


            return response;
        }
```

This will send the following json

```
 {"Id":9939,"Name":"Zander"}
```

Comment: This answer is still correct, although why AddJsonBody doesn't add it to the request's body seems strange and inappropriately named.